# ANTLR4 - how to specify line does not start with specific character?

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4

Given the following example from ***The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference***

```
STUFF: ~[\t\r\n]+ ; // match any chars except tab, newline
```

I am trying to define an alternate path for a line that starts with `*`.  For example:

```
line : ~ASTERIX keys ;
ASTERIX : '*';
```

But, I don't want to match everything that is not `ASTERIX`, I want the `line` rule to execute when the line does not start with `ASTERIX` and then begin the rest of the matching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could redefine the `ASTERISK` rule to only match `*` appearing at the beginning of a line.

```
ASTERISK : '*' {_input.LA(-2) == '\n'}?;
```

Then your `line` rule can simply not reference `ASTERISK`.

```
line : keys;
```

As long as `keys` doesn't allow `ASTERISK` as the first symbol, then `line` can't match a line where the first token is `ASTERISK`.